# Access localhost hosted on Android device from laptop over wifi

Tags: javascript, android, web

I have a localhost webpage hosted on an android app. I want to access the page from a laptop over wifi. Is there a good way to do so?

Comment: Find the ip of the android app.  Make sure the devices are on the same network, or that ip is accessible, and navigate to that IP instead of localhost.

Comment: @Taplar What if I want to connect to the wifi hosted by the android device?

Comment: That android device is connected to it's network via some ip.  Or if it is hosting it's own network it should still have an ip that the other devices connect to.  That is the ip you will want to use in place of localhost, on the other devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can access localhost in android app multiple ways:

- **Using IP address and access wirelessly**

  1. If both laptop and android device accessing same wifi network, Go to terminal and execute this command to get the `inet` address.

     `ipconfig getifaddr en1`
  2. You will get an IP address, You can use this ip address in you android to access your localhost.
- **Using Chrome developer tools:**

  1. Connect your mobile to laptop via datacable. Enable USB debugging from settings -> Developer options
  2. Goto Chrome -> Settings -> More Tools -> Developer Tools -> : (Settings on top right corner) -> More tools -> Remote devices
  3. Check **Enable Port forwarding** and enter port number and url. Eg, If you are accessing `localhost:8080`, port numer is 8080, url is `localhost:8080`.
  4. In your android app, Provide the same url and you can access it
- **Using Adb `reverse` port**

  1. If you have adb (Android debug bridge) installed in your system, connect the USB debugging enabled smartphone using data cable and execute this below terminal command.

     `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8080`
  2. After executing this command, you can use url `localhost:8081` in your android app

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just wanna double check, is this for "viewing localhost hosted in android app on laptop"?

Comment: No.  This is other way around. The above solution is accessing laptop's local host in Android. But you can try 1st solution, get the ip address from Android and try accessing from laptop.